# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree: Angular NEST.js, Mongoose

Tags: angular, mongoose, nestjs

I try to update my Nestjs Backend and have dependency conflicts. Unfortunately I can't figure out what the cause is. I have already updated mongoose and also updated NestJS to the latest version.

ERROR:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: server@0.0.2
npm ERR! Found: mongoose@6.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR!   mongoose@"6.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer mongoose@"5.10.0 - 5.10.18" from @typegoose/typegoose@7.6.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@typegoose/typegoose
npm ERR!   @typegoose/typegoose@"^7.4.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/XX/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/XX/.npm/_logs/2022-08-07T19_52_18_976Z-debug-0.log
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "concurrently --handle-input \"wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon\" \"tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json\" ",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && npm run build",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.8",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.8",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.8",
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^7.4.8",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "mongoose": "6.5.1",
    "nestjs-typegoose": "^7.1.38",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.8",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.7",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "supertest": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.7",
    "ts-node": "8.1.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "3.8.0",
    "tslint": "5.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.3",
    "wait-on": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

It is a NestJS backend with Mongoose. Unfortunately, I can't make sense of the error message

Thank you!

Comment: that version of `@typegoose/typegoose` has `mongoose` v5 as a peer dependency. But you have v6 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade `@typegoose/typegoose` to its latest version (v9)

```
$ npm view @typegoose/typegoose@7 peerDependencies
@typegoose/typegoose@7.0.0 { mongoose: '^5.9.10', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.12' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.1.0 { mongoose: '^5.9.14', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.19' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.1.1 { mongoose: '^5.9.14', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.19' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.1.2 { mongoose: '^5.9.14', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.20' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.1.3 { mongoose: '^5.9.14', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.20' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.2.0 { mongoose: '^5.9.17', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.21' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.3.0 { mongoose: '^5.9.22', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.30' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.3.1 { mongoose: '^5.9.22', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.30' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.3.2 { mongoose: '^5.9.22', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.30' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.3.3 { mongoose: '^5.9.22', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.30' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.3.4 { mongoose: '^5.9.22', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.30' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.3.5 { mongoose: '^5.9.22', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.30' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.0 { mongoose: '^5.10.4', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.36' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.1 { mongoose: '^5.10.4', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.36' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.2 { mongoose: '^5.10.4', '@types/mongoose': '^5.7.36' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.3 { mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18', '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.1' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.4 { mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18', '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.1' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.5 { mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18', '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.2' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.6 { mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18', '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.2' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.7 { '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.2', mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.4.8 { '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.2', mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.5.0 { '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.2', mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.6.0 { '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.2', mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.6.1 { '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.2', mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.6.2 { '@types/mongoose': '^5.10.2', mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18' }
@typegoose/typegoose@7.6.3 { '@types/mongoose': '~5.10.2', mongoose: '5.10.0 - 5.10.18' }
```

as you can see above, v7 requires `mongoose` v5 (but you have v6 installed).

---

```bash
$ npm view @typegoose/typegoose peerDependencies
{ mongoose: '~6.5.0' }
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it worked. I installed the necessary packages with the @latest decorator. I also used the npm outdated command to find other packages that needed an update